# how to execute for loop inside chroot enviroment

Tags: for-loop, sh, freebsd, chroot

executing this script and it returns nothing in variable i in fact it isn't creating one how to overcome this problem

```
chroot $ROOT /bin/sh -c "for i in ../autoconf-patch/* ; do patch < $i ; done; ./configure ; make install "
```

$i returns nothing 
/bin/sh : Syntax error; ";" unexpected (expecting word)
meaning it considers ";" after the command patch < $i which implies that $i is empty and throws that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use single quotes, for example:

```
/bin/sh -c 'i=3; echo $i'
```

If you use double quotes `"` the variables will be expanded, you could try this from your example:

```
chroot $ROOT /bin/sh -c 'for i in ../autoconf-patch/* ; do patch < $i ; done; ./configure ; make install'
```